# How to deploy reacr SSR application to AWS and remove port

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, server-side-rendering

I have created an React SSR app and deployed on Server
I have zipped all local folders and uploaded to server that includes:

```html
node_modules
package.json
webpack
bundle.js
```

I run the server by executing node bundle.js its runs on port. now browser i can run example.com:3002, 
What i want is to remove port 3002 from my site and it should work by example

Comment: I think you need to set default port as 3002

Comment: yes but i want website should run without port like example.com

Comment: it would. your server will automatically redirect all request to 3002